# Calling Mongoose schema methods from a different schema, is this good practice?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, mongoose

I know that it is possible to do this, but my question is whether there is a good reason not to do it, or is there a better way? I feel like it could make the code easier to follow and potentially make testing easier, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Example Code:

```
postSchema.methods.publishPost = function(data, cb) {
  var self = this,
    options = options || {};

  mongoose.model('Version').findById(data.version).exec(function(err, version) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    mongoose.model('Translation').findTranslatedVersion(version, function(err, translation) {
      if(err) return cb(err);

      publisher.publish(self, translation ? translation : version, function(err, published) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        self.save(published);
      });
    });
  });
}
```